# Function not being run after if statement in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension for version 87.0.4280.66.

It's a little fun script library to mess around with apps.

Right now, I'm making a Chrome extension that when you click a button, it adds on to an [Instructure](https://instructure.com) link to make it play confetti.

I'm making it check if there are parameters present or not, as well as if it is an Instructure link too.

The problem is when I call the function, it doesn't run it at all.

Here is the `popup.js` that is responsible for updating the URL to add the parameter `confetti=true`.

```
let confetti = document.getElementById('confetti');

const regEx = /https:\/\/cbsd\.instructure\.com\/courses\/([0-9]{5})\/assignments\/([0-9]{6})\?module_item_id=([0-9]{7})|https:\/\/cbsd\.instructure\.com\/courses\/([0-9]{5})\/assignments\/([0-9]{6})/g;

var getParams = function (url) {
    var params = {};
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = url;
    var query = parser.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return params;
};
function error(message)
{
  var notification = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Error",
    iconUrl: "images/error.ico",
    message: message
  }
  chrome.notifications.create(notification);
}
function isCanvas(domain)
{
  return regEx.test(domain);
}
function isMod(dom)
{
  var parameters = getParams(dom);
  if (parameters) {
    return(true)
  } else {
    return(false)
  }
}

confetti.onclick = function(element) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
  let domain = tabs[0].url;
  var canvasCheck = isCanvas(domain)
  if (canvasCheck === true) {
    error(isMod(domain).toString());
    /*/ if (andOrQuestion) {
      let newUrl = domain + "&confetti=true";
      chrome.tabs.update({url: newUrl});
    } else {
      let newUrl = domain + "?confetti=true"
      chrome.tabs.update({url: newUrl});
    } /*/
  } else {
    // error("You are not on an assignment page!")
  }
  });
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to answer this question and have a nice day!

Comment: What is `isCanvas`?

Comment: `isCanvas` is just: `return regEx.test(domain);`

Comment: Is the `error()` function part of the Chrome extension library?

Comment: No, it's a function that I created that creates a notification just for debugging

Comment: Use devtools to debug the code: set a breakpoint and then run through the code by using the stepping hotkey/button. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Hasn't seemed to help, I have updated the code with what I have tried so far